# Imbed Blog post into html page and provide admin login page for updating post

Tags: php, python, html, css, wordpress

I need some help please.

I'm trying to building a blog site but I want to maintain my own page layout and styles. I only want to embed the blog post to appear in the div provided. I will also need a way I can always update the blog post through an admin login page.
I tried using wordpress but it didn't allow me to use my own layout and style, rather i have to use their theme. 
Which method or framework will you best suggest.
Here is the link for what I'm trying to do.
www.fortwebtech.com/blog2.html

Comment: Well you can use wordpress and then just read how to convert your html css template into working wordpress template if you want a customize wordpress theme. You can visit wordpress theme development documentation here  https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion